# Cannot make UWP button and WebView2 visible at same time

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, webview2

I have a WebView2 that navigates correctly in a UWP app. The webview navigate uri is set in the page `OnNavigatedTo` event. I've added a button to the xaml form but I can see either the button or the webview but not both.

I see the button but not the WebView if I do this

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            x:Name="MyButton"
            Padding="0,10"
            AccessKey="R"
            Click="DoStuff"
            Style="{StaticResource StuffButton}"
            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Do Stuff">
        <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="R" Modifiers="Control" />
        </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </Button>
        <WebView
                    Name="MyWebView"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If I remove the StackPanel like this

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <Button
            x:Name="MyButton"
            Padding="0,10"
            AccessKey="R"
            Click="DoStuff"
            Style="{StaticResource StuffButton}"
            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Do Stuff">
        <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="R" Modifiers="Control" />
        </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </Button>
        <WebView
                    Name="MyWebView"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

I see the WebView navigates correctly but the button is no longer visible. How do I show both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `WebView2` in `StackPanel`, you need to **define the Height and Width of WebView2**. If it is not defined, UWP cannot calculate the position of `WebView2` in the `StackPanel`, so WebView2 will not be displayed.

```
<StackPanel>
           ...
     <WebView
          Width="1000"
          Height="1000"
          Name="MyWebView"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
       Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In order to get a better display effect, it is recommended that you use the **Grid layout** like [Grid.RowDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowdefinitions?view=winrt-22621) and put the `WebView2` in the specified row and column.

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 
        <Button 
            Grid.Row="0"
        x:Name="MyButton"
            Width="100"
            Height="50"
        Padding="0,10"
        AccessKey="R"
        Click="MyButton_Click"
        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Do Stuff">
            <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
                <KeyboardAccelerator Key="R" Modifiers="Control" />
            </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </Button>
        <WebView
            Grid.Row="1"                
                Name="MyWebView"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>

</Grid>
```